# state params undefined using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I can navigate to a screen but params are undefined, state is just:

```
{
key: "id-1574950261181-7",
routeName: "Video Player"
}
```

Navigate from:

```
  render() {
    const {
      id,
      title,
      description,
      video,
      preview,
      push,
      dispatch,
      testLink,
      navigate
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.episode}
        activeOpacity={1}
        underlayColor="#808080"
        onPress={() => {
          navigate("VideoPlayer", { tester: id });
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.title}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

My `VideoPlayerScreen` (for brevity) gives me :

```
import React from "react";
import {
...
} from "react-native";
...
...
class VideoPlayerScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onShare = this.onShare.bind(this);
    this.navigateScreen = this.navigateScreen.bind(this);
    this.bookmarkVideo = this.bookmarkVideo.bind(this);
    this.loadRecapVideo = this.loadRecapVideo.bind(this);
  }
  ....
  render() {
    const {
       videos,
       bookmarkVideo,
       navigate,
       state: {
         params: { id }
       }
     } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params);
    let videoProps = videos.find(obj => obj.id == id);

    return (<View />)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  bookmarkVideo: id => dispatch(bookmarkVideo(id))
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    videos: state.tcApp.videos
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(VideoPlayerScreen);
```

Comment: Still I am unable to understand how come `const {navigate}=this.props` is working. It should be `const {navigation} = this.props` or `const {navigate} = this.props.navigation`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `react-native-navigation 4x` you should change the props variable

from:

`const {
      ...
      navigate,
    } = this.props;`

to:

`const {
      ...
      navigation,
    } = this.props;`

and call it like:

`onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("VideoPlayer", { tester: id });
        }}`

Official Doc: [React Native Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)

Friendly.

Comment: Thanks im using ^3.0.9